# replace two same character with whitespace

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the string below with whitespaces using javascript

```
    function replaceString()
    {
        var str = "ABC**EFG";
        return str.replace(/\*/g, " ");
    }
```

I received the result as `ABC EFG` but I expect the result to come with two whitespace.
I also tried the same thing using php str.replace but still get the same result.

Is there any other methods i can used to replace the individual asterisk with whitespace??

P/S: The return string will be used as part of the sql query

---

**[UPDATE]**

I ended up return the string without any replacement to sql, then I use sql `replace` function to perform replacement in the query.

Comment: It's probably replacing it with 2 spaces, but the browser is only rendering it as a single space, per HTMLs WS squashing behavior.

Comment: it does, but html only shows 1 whitespace character. use `&nbsp;`

Comment: use ```&nbsp;``` and not " " because in html many whitespaces is only one whitespace

Comment: +1 to @SeanBright. Try to use `&nbsp;` instead.

Comment: but when i return the string, i only get the first portion "ABC"

Comment: @noobie: update your question with the exact usage that causes your error.

Comment: since you're using it for a SQL query, keep the function as it is. If you use `return str.replace(/\*/g, '&nbsp;');` it will look fine in the browser but definitely won't work properly for a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the best solution, I replace those special characters using `percent-encoding (URL-encoding)`

for my case: `str.replace(/\*/g, "%20");`

Answer (score 3):

If you're displaying the resulting string in an HTML element then two or more whitespaces will be displayed as only one whitespace.  To workaround this fact, use `&nbsp;` instead:

```
return str.replace(/\*/g, '&nbsp;');
```

Comment: Should be added, this is only relevant if you print it to the html.

Comment: @WhyMe: yes, that's why I started with "if you're displaying the resulting string in an HTML element"...

Comment: but when i return the string, i only get the first portion "ABC"

Comment: Works for me. Oh, and sorry :).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return str.replace(/\*/g, '&#160;');
```

Comment: same issue as `&nbsp;`, the string will be cut off

Answer (score 0):

Buddy the problem is with the HTML compiler which has its own special rules of parsing 
So it parses multiple spaces into one.This can work for HTML only.
Thats why use the GIFT tag

```
.
```

`<pre>
<p id="para"></p>
</pre>
<script>  function replaceString()
    {
        var str = "ABC**EFG";
        return str.replace(/\*/g," ");
    }
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=replaceString();
</script>



    <script> 
    function replaceString()
        {   var str1=String.fromCharCode(32,32);
            var str = "ABC**EFG";
            return str.replace(/\*/g,str1);
        }
    alert(replaceString());
    </script>`

return of function from above code can be used directly in mysql...